# Is there an Excel's GRG Nonlinear solver equivalent in Python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am using Python to solve nonlinear problems and I would like to achieve the same outcome as Excel GRG Nonlinear. But you know Excel is slow so I want to use Python. Are there any packages I can use to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no such solver (at least no popular one / trusted), except for some commercial one based on the same method. There are probably much better candidates available, but A) it's unclear what you are doing exactly and expect from a solution and B) asking for software-recommendations is off-topic

Comment: This is off-topic, and too broad/vague.

Comment: @AMC: it's not off-topic.